# Automatically move data from one sheet to another in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a spreadsheet that i keep track of tasks i need to do, once complete i enter a date in the last column. What i want is for that completed task to be moved to sheet 2.

At present i have sheet 1 named SUD_schedule and i want the completed row of data to be moved to sheet 2 named SUD_archive. I've looked through the forum posts already and i've tried a variation of scripts but so far no luck. The closest i have come is this script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();//Original sheet
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];//target sheet
   // to act on only one sheet, check the sheet name here:
  //If it si not first sheet, it will do nothing
  if (sheet1.getSheetName() != "SUD_schedule") {
    return; 
  }
  //Get Row and column index of active cell.
  var rowIndex = sheet1.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var colIndex =  sheet1.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  //If the selected column is 10th and it is not a header row
  if (colIndex == 16 && rowIndex > 1) {
    //Get the data from the current row
   var data = sheet1.getRange(rowIndex,1,1,9).getValues();
   var lastRow2; 
    (sheet2.getLastRow()==0)?lastRow2=1:lastRow2=sheet2.getLastRow()+1;
    //Copy the data to the lastRow+1th row in target sheet
    sheet2.getRange(lastRow2,1,1,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Column P (16) is the task complete date, row 1 is frozen and contains column headers.

Can anybody help show where i'm going wrong.

Kind regards
Den

Comment: Have you set up a trigger?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers

If that is not the problem, could you provide a link to the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not generic and you are more complicating your objective. Below will work out your need.

```
    function onEdit(){

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

     var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('SUD_schedule');
     var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('SUD_archive');

     var dateColumn = "16";
     var array = []

     var range = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, sheet1.getLastRow(), dateColumn); 

      for (var i = 2; i <= sheet1.getLastRow(); i++) //i iterates from 2 as you say R1 is header
      {
        if(isValidDate(range.getCell(i, dateColumn).getValue()) == true) //checking if any values on column16 is valid date
        {
          data = sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, dateColumn).getValues(); //Getting the range values of particular row where C16 is date

          for (var j = 0; j < dateColumn; j++) //Adding the row in array
          {
          array.push(data[0][j]);
          }

        }
        if(array.length > 0)
        {
        sheet2.appendRow(array); //Appending the row in sheet2
        array = [];
        sheet1.deleteRow(i); //deleting the row in sheet as you said you want to move, if you copy remove this and next line
        i=i-1; //managing i value after deleting a row.
        }

      }


    }

//Below function return true if the given String is date, else false

    function isValidDate(d) {
      if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" )
        return false;
      return !isNaN(d.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the syntax you have as used below is entirely correct.

```
(sheet2.getLastRow()==0)?lastRow2=1:lastRow2=sheet2.getLastRow()+1;
sheet2.getRange(lastRow2,1,1,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

What I know will work for certain is if you omit the variable lastRow2 all together and use this instead.

```
sheet2.getRange(getLastRow+1,1,1,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Joachin's answer, here is how you can adapt that code if you don't have the date in the last row. In the below shown part of the code replace `Lastcolumnumber` with your last column.

```
//Getting the range values of particular row where C16 is date
data = sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, LASTCOLUMNNUMBER).getValues(); 

//Adding the row in array
for (var j = 0; j < LASTCOLUMNNUMBER; j++)
```